# Configuring sendmail for use of Gmail with SMTP on digital ocean

Tags: smtp, sendmail, gmail

[I followed these instructions](https://linuxconfig.org/configuring-gmail-as-sendmail-email-relay), and I have this running from the command line. I run a test from the command line like so:

```
echo "Just testing my sendmail gmail relay" \
| mail -s "Sendmail gmail Relay" my-email@example.com
```

There is a delay, but it does eventually send the email...

When I call mail() from php, it's timing out or dying with a "504 Gateway Time-out" error.

In the article it says "If you will experience substitutional delays after executing the above command to most likely cause is that you have not configured your host with FQDN.  Check your logs for a warning:"

I don't find anything in the logs. I have restarted the server, but can't think of anything else to try... I believe the hosts are configured properly with:

```
127.0.1.1 server-name
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

I'm not sure what else to try at this point....

Any tips ideas or advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `server-name` nor `localhost` are fully qualified; a fully qualified hostname instead looks like `server-name.example.org` or `localhost.localdomain`. `sendmail` will show what domain names it is using via the command

```
sendmail -d0.1 < /dev/null
```

It may also be helpful to find the mail logs on your system (this depends on the `syslog` daemon configuration) and see exactly which `sendmail` process (or processes) are complaining about what, as I do not know whether whatever your PHP code is is going through `sendmail` like your command line example is (`sendmail` -> `MSA` -> `MTA`) or whether it is submitting directly to the `MTA` via `SMTP`.

Sendmail depends heavily on properly configured DNS; you might try to kluge around it via

```
    FEATURE(`nocanonify', `canonify_hosts')
    define(`confDIRECT_SUBMISSION_MODIFIERS', `C')
```

in the `submit.mc` configuration, though this could break things (and without the logs I don't know if that is a source of the issue). You may also need to setup masquerade so that the addresses are properly standardized before being lobbed off to gmail.

Yet another option would be instead to send mail out via something like `ssmtp`.